# VSCode emmet adds extra attributes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm using VSCode 1.69.2 (Universal). Emmet support is enabled and is working fine. But it adds extra attributes as well while using it in **React JS files**

When I type

1. `lab.my-class` and hit TAB, it completes to `<label htmlFor="" className="my-class"></label>` whereas I had intended only `<label className="my-class"></label>`
2. `inp` and hit TAB, it completes to `<input type="text" name="" id="" />` whereas I had intended only `<input />`

I understand this is useful too. But if there were a way to toggle between these two choices it could be great. Couldn't find anything on this anywhere. Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this references can help you https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets 
good luck

Comment: a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: 
(add context around the link)[https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259] so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, 
then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. 
(Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers]